# Setting Space Between Paragraph in A Custom Class

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, document-classes

I've been trying set space between paragraph to 3 spaces with 1.5 line spacing on text (based on my thesis requirement). Searching around, looks like everyone suggest either using the `parskip` package or writing your own class. Since this is my thesis, I'm thinking about learning to write my own class, but I haven't find a good documentation on that (can't afford TeX Companion).

Looking inside the `artikel3` class suggested in `parskip` documentation I see that there's two possibility of doing this, and I'm not sure which one is right:

1. Redefine the paragraph like this:

   ```
   \newcommand*\paragraph{
       \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
           {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
           {-1em}%
           {\normalfont\normalsize\ParaFont}}
   ```
2. Setting up the `\parskip` to 3 spaces and then setting it back to normal for all other elements (ToC, list, title, etc)

I have a hunch that it is the second option, but I can't see how I can set 1.5 line spacing with 3 line spacing between paragraph. I have zero clue on how to do this. Could you help me?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\paragraph` and `\parskip` are for different purposes. `\parskip` is used for vertical space between paragraphs when paragraphs are separated by a blank line in the source. `\paragraph{<paragraph header>}` is a sectioning command.  Probably you have to define both.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\parskip}{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}
\renewcommand*\paragraph{
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
        {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
        {-1em}%
        {\normalfont\normalsize}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing

\lipsum

\paragraph{Lorem}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: So if I want to have one spacing for list, ToC, and other elements that are effected by `parskip` I have to set them back?

Comment: Yes, it affects `\parskip` globally. You have to modify elements using `\parskip`.